# Integral of dirac delta function times another another function

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is defined with two properties:
1) At $x=0$ its value is $\infty$ and everywhere else it is $0$
2) Area under the curve is $1$

How does above definition result in 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx = f(0) $$
?
Shouldn't the integral evaluate to $\delta(0)f(0)$?

Comment: That's just by definition, so there is not a really a "should". Why do you expect it to be other value?

Comment: Your definition of Dirac delta is wrong.  It is a "baby" definition for those who do not know much mathematics.  That integral is closer to the real definition, although still needs some explanation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: Oh so there is more to the definition? @GEdgar wikipidea also has just those two properties..

Comment: wikipedia:  `...a function equal to zero everywhere except for zero and whose integral over the entire real line is equal to one`

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=1$. Then $\int \delta(x)=1=f(0)$, so there’s really no way to have any additional dependence on $\delta(x).$ Also, 1) is heuristic not a rigorous definition.

Comment: Also, you’ve ignored the sentence right after the bit you quoted from Wikipedia: “ This is merely a heuristic characterization. The Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense as no function defined on the real numbers has these properties.”

Comment: `...a function equal to zero everywhere except for zero and whose integral over the entire real line is equal to one` ... In fact, there is no such function.  Read down further on that Wiipedia page to Definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading about distributions (generalised functions), e.g.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) . The point is, Dirac's $\delta$-function is not a function at all, at least not in the usual sense. What you have given as a "definition" is merely an intuition for it.

What $\delta$-function *is* is this: it is a linear functional that maps a certain class of functions (infintely smooth real functions that are nonzero only on a bounded set of $\mathbb R$) into real numbers, the following way:

$$\delta(f)=f(0)$$

Now, the right side looks like your right-hand side, but what about the left-hand side? One should note that, if $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb{R}$ is a locally integrable function, then you can use it to define *another* functional of similar type:

$$T_g(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$$

... and because for a given $T_g$ the function $g$ can be proven to be uniquely determined (up to a set of zero measure), then you can, in a sense, identify $T_g$ with $g$.

Now, in a common abuse of notation, we imagine that the functional $\delta$ is also identified with a *fictional* function $\delta(x)$ such that:

$$\delta(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx$$

so *that* is where the left-hand side is coming from. This is an abuse of notation because no such function $\delta(x)$ exists.